# Right Indent parameter does not apply to Jasper Report HTML export

Tags: html, jasper-reports, padding, indentation

I have a text field defined as follows:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0" isBlankWhenNull="true">
    <reportElement uuid="2f924751-c6a9-4603-95b3-41046f59b9d1" x="591" y="0" width="105" height="20"/>
    <box>
        <pen lineWidth="1.0"/>
    </box>
    <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
        <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="8"/>
        <paragraph leftIndent="2" rightIndent="2"/>
    </textElement>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{PAYMENTS_CNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

when I export report to HTML, this text field hasn't got a padding. There is no space between text in the cell and border.
How can it be fixed?

Comment: You should use *leftPadding* attribute for left padding, for exmaple. You can set padding in *iReport* with help of context menu *Padding And Borders*, for example. The box with left padding: `<box leftPadding="10">`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use leftPadding attribute for left padding, for exmaple. You can set padding in iReport with help of context menu Padding And Borders, for example. The box with left padding:  –  Alex K